# matshow: colormap the values in numpy array to binary

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I try to visualize a numpy array to image.
But the array contains negative values or values that out of bound.

I have get an image successfully, but I have some question about gray scale.

How does it interpret through the colormap ?. 
(In principle, if the array is a float array scaled to 0..1, it should be interpreted as a grayscale image)
So, what is the principle?

Thank you very much for your collaboration.

```
V = np.loadtxt('np.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)       
ax.matshow(V, cmap = matplotlib.cm.binary)
plt.show()

The np array like:
[ [....]
....
 [  7.47859700e-03  -4.42994573e-03  -3.15871151e-02   4.57486308e-02
    4.58066400e-02   7.81800849e-02   1.41268438e-01   2.67617603e-01
    3.98583385e-01   3.85877649e-01   1.92501545e-01   2.65159152e-01
    2.10979793e-01   2.48940247e-01   1.75112904e-01  -3.06361785e-02
    2.74774650e-01   1.81465161e-01   4.23131349e-03  -3.56762525e-02
   -1.72089055e-02  -4.25273422e-02  -2.63428158e-02  -4.59487077e-02
   -2.30976482e-02  -4.45129524e-02   8.95580352e-03   1.56548770e-03]
...
[...] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The range of values can be set with `vmin` and `vmax` and the colormap will be scaled accordingly. This is performed in the `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` class, passed behind the scenes to the `ScalarMappable` mixin when creating a colour plot like `matshow`. The values for the colormap will be obtained from the normalised data by something like `(V-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)`, then mapped to rgb or whatever. The actual code used to do this from `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` is,

```
# ma division is very slow; we can take a shortcut
resdat = result.data
resdat -= vmin
resdat /= (vmax - vmin)
```

If you don't specify `vmin` or `vmax`, then they are obtained automatically from the minimum and maximum values of your data `vmin=V.min()` and `vmax = V.max()`. As a minimal example of setting these limits,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#V = np.loadtxt('np.txt')
#Generate random data with negative values
V = np.random.randn(100,100) - 1.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)       
im = ax.matshow(V, cmap = plt.cm.binary, vmin = -3., vmax=3.)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Where im here is a `ScalarMappable`.